# If $A^k$ commutes with $B$ then $A$ commutes with $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ are two $n \times n$ Complex matrices. Assume that $(A-I)^n=0$ and $A^kB=BA^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then I want to prove that $AB= BA$.

Clearly $1$ is the only eigen value of $A$ and also $A^k$ and $B$ are simultaneously triangulable. But how do I get down to $A$ to commute with $B$. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{N}$ has to mean $\left\{1,2,3,\ldots\right\}$ for this to be correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hint.* Try to prove that $A$ is a polynomial in $A^k$.

**Edit.** To prove the hint, you may follow darij grinberg's comment below. I did essentially the same thing, but from a matrix analytic rather than linear algebraic perspective: I considered the primary matrix function $f(X)=(I+X)^{1/k}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{k!}X^i$ for a nilpotent matrix $X$ associated with the scalar function $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/k}$. Put $X=A^k-I$ and we are done.

Alternatively, the hint can be proved using only Jordan forms, but the argument is much longer.

1. Let $J$ be the Jordan form of $A$. Since all eigenvalues of $A$ are ones, we may write $J=J_{m_1}\oplus J_{m_2}\oplus\cdots\oplus J_{m_b}$, where $1\le m_1\le m_2\le\cdots\le m_b$ and $J_m$ denotes a Jordan block of size $m$ for the eigenvalue $1$.
2. Note that if $r\ge0$ and $m<n$, then $J_m^r$ coincides with the leading principal $m\times m$ submatrix of $J_n^r$. Hence $p(J_m^k)$ coincides with a leading principal submatrix of $p(J_n^k)$ for any polynomial $p$.
3. It follows that if $p(J_n^k)=J_n$, then $p(J_m^k)=J_m$ for every $m<n$. This is true in particular when $m\in\{m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_b\}$. Consequently, $p(A^k)=A$.
4. Hence the problem boils down to finding a polynomial $p$ such that $p(J_n^k)=J_n$. This should be straightforward and I will leave it to you.

Comment: I was trying to prove your hint. I was thinking that if I can show that  $A^k$ has a cyclic vector then since $A^k$ commutes with $A$, $A$ would have been a polynomial in $A^k$. But it may not be the case that $A^k$ has a cyclic vector. Can you kindly give me one more hint to prove your hint ?

Comment: @user1551: How to show that $A$ is a polynomial in $A^k ?$

Comment: @user371231 one way is to show that $(A-I)^j$ is a polynomial of $A^k$ for $j = 1,\dots,n-1$, starting with $j=n-1$.

Comment: My favorite way of proving the hint is to recall Newton's binomial formula $\left(1+x\right)^r = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \dbinom{r}{i} x^i$ for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. This is, per se, an equality between formal power series in the indeterminate $x$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. But since the matrix $A^k - I$ is nilpotent (make sure you understand why!), we can substitute $A^k - I$ for $x$ in this formula (make sure you understand why!), and apply it to $r = 1/k$, thus obtaining $A$ on the left hand side (make sure you understand how!), and on the right hand side a polynomial in $A^k - I$.

Comment: I never knew you could put non-integers into binomial coefficients. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: For the infinite sum $f(X)=(I+X)^{1/k}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{k!}X^i$ to converge, it should also be shown that $|| X^i || = ||(A^k- I)^i||$ converges fast enough (to be specific, we need $||(A^k- I)^i|| <r^i$ for some $r\in (0,1)$.) But this gap can be easily filled in terms of the spectral radius theorem.

Comment: @Song There is no need to do this. Since $X$ is nilpotent, the infinite sum is actually a finite sum (or more specifically, a sum of no more than $n$ terms).

Comment: @Song $A-I$ is nilpotent. Therefore $1$ is an eigenvalue fo $A$ of multiplicity $n$. Hence $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$ of multiplicity $n$, meaning that $A^k$ is nilpotent. You may also triangularise $A$ first to see this.

Comment: @User1551 Oops, I was wrong. I was confused with the infinite-dimensional case where $\sigma(A) =\{0\}$ does not guarantee that $A$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ has only $1$ as eigenvalue then it is invertible (and of the form $I+N$ where $N$ is nilpotent with $N^n=0$).

$A $ is satisfying also any equation   $(A^i-I)^n=0$ so we can write

$(A-I)^n=0, (A^2-I)^n=0, \dots (A^k-I)^n=0$.

Also we can write ${A^k} B(A^k)^{-1}=B$.
In similar fashion

${A^k} B(A^k)^{-1}=({A^k})^{-1} B(A^k)$

${A^{2k}} B =  B(A^{2k})$, etc..

For any natural $m$:

${A^{mk}} B =  B(A^{mk})$

If powers  $(A^k)^m$ could be a basis for expression  of $A$ then commutativity would follow...