# nilpotent endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

$E$ is a linear space and $\dim(E)=n$
$f$ is endomorphism of $E$  $\ f^n = 0$ and $\ f^{n-1} \neq 0$

for $x$ in $E$ that $f^{n-1} \neq 0$ we showed that $(x,f(x),...,f^{n-1}(x) )$ is a basis of $E$ 
for g is an endomorphism of E

how to desmonstrate that $g \circ f = f \circ g$ is equivalent to $g \in \operatorname{vect} (id,f,...,f^{n-1})$

Comment: sorry my mistake also knowing that g in vect (x,....,$\ f^{n-1} $(x) ) we can easily show that $g \circ f = f \circ g$

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004924/if-ak-commutes-with-b-then-a-commutes-with-b).

Answer (score 1):

First, if $g=\sum_{i\ge 0}\lambda_i f^i$, then we will obviously have $f\circ g=g\circ f$.

For the converse, assume $f\circ g=g\circ f$.
Let $\lambda_i$ be the coefficients of $g(x)$ in the basis $(x,f(x),f^2(x),\dots, f^{n-1}(x))$, i.e.
$$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lambda_i f^i(x)$$
Now the assumption implies $g(f^k(x))=f^k(g(x))$ for every $k$, and hence $$g(\,f^k(x)\,)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lambda_i f^{k+i}(x)\ =\ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lambda_i f^i(\,f^k(x)\,)\,.$$
Since $(f^k(x))_{k=0}^{n-1}$ is a basis, we get $g\ =\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lambda_i f^i$.

[Note that we didn't use that $f$ is nilpotent, only that $(x,f(x),\dots,f^{n-1}(x))$ is a basis.]

Comment: thank you very much